# Questions about the angler quests?

Tags: terraria

so I've recently found the angler. my questions are the following:

1. does the quests restart/lose every time i talk to him.
2. whats the duration of mission once i talked to him.
3. is there specific locations where can i find the fish he wants?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the terraria wiki :

> The Angler is an NPC that doesn't sell anything, but rather assigns quests to players. Quest objectives generally involve fishing him up rare fish from different biomes, for which he dispenses various rewards.

Also from the wiki :

> Once the Angler is acquired, a new Quest is always in effect each day. If you don't complete a Quest before the day is over (4:30am the following day), a new Quest begins, whether or not you speak to the Angler again.
>   It is possible to complete Quests without actually speaking to the Angler to find out what the quest is. Though most Quests require fishing in a specific environment, so your chances of success are better if you speak to him to find out where to fish. Once you complete a quest, you must wait until the following in-game day to embark on another.
>   The Angler may spawn directly on an Antlion, so if the player is not fast enough he will die.
>   If the Angler dies while asleep, he will vanish in a puff of smoke and respawn immediately somewhere in the Ocean biome.

[Source](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Angler)

I think this pretty much answers your question. Acording to the wiki you can talk to the angler npc to ask him where to best fish for the specific fish he asked you to get.

Comment: Do note that the locations of the different targets might not be totally correct. Some fish I could not find at all.

Comment: Unlikely, if the angler said you should go to the jungle biome and you didnt find any fish there you didnt try hard enough. Its (as stated by the wiki) a rare fish.

Comment: http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Talk:Fishing#Fishing_Corrections Just saying. I had trouble with some. Others I could find multiples of easily enough (using the banking the quest item exploit). Some I could not find at all.