# What happens if I missed one angler quest? Do the rewards resets?

Tags: terraria

I do not know if I should miss one quest. Maybe the reward system may get resets if I miss one

Comment: Also see: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/184452/questions-about-the-angler-quests

Answer (score 2):

Missing a day does nothing to the angler quest or rewards. You're fine. The only thing the rewards depend on is the number of times you do them. Short and sweet.

[See this page for more details.](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Angler) I'd recommend reading as much as you want on the Wikipedia for Terraria. It's very robust, and has a LOT of information about the game, most of which isn't something most of us wouldn't pick up on otherwise (I know I sure didn't!).